# openshift mysql database schema creation script

Tags: mysql, database, openshift

I am using Redhat Cloud OpenShift (rhcloud) and I have the MySQL cartridge.

I would like to be able to create a database schema using a script, as opposed to manually with phpMyAdmin.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think the question is quite broad. You can either run the schema script by phpMyAdmin or by your app that is using the database. You can also [ssh into your app](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-remote-connection.html#common-commands) and supply the schema script that way or [forward the mysql port](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html) and use a tool of your preference.

Comment: DB migrations are a nice way to do it, especially if you set up Jenkins to kick them off for you. I've used this one in nodejs before, it's nice and straightforward - https://www.npmjs.com/package/db-migrate

Answer (score 0):

Openshift contains the MySQL Command-Line Tool

**Connect to Openshift:**

- Connect to openshift: `$ rhc ssh <app_name>`
- Connect to the MySQL Command-Line Tool: `$ mysql`

**Create the database schema:**

`$ mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password -e "CREATE DATABASE mydeebee"`

**Verify the creation:**

- Connect to the MySQL Command-Line Tool: `$ mysql --user=user_name --password=your_password`
- Inspect the schemas: `mysql> SHOW SCHEMAS;` (don't forget `;`)
- Or verify with a connection to the new database and SQL: `SHOW SCHEMAS`

[Link to MySql CLI commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html)

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help),it will be useful to put  your content quality up